# How do I combine data from two rows with the same foreign key in sql/linq

Tags: sql, linq

I have a table for payslips which can contain multiple payslips with the same employee. Each payslip has a hours_worked column. I want to be able to get each employee's hours worked within any period of time I give it.

For example if there are two payslips from Jan 2021 - Feb 2021 belonging to Employee 1 and he worked a total of 60 hours within those two months, I want to get 60 hours worked in one row. Same goes for every other employee.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a JOIN, and GROUP BY, and SUM().

Something like:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.Name, Hours = SUM(P.Hours)
FROM Employee E
JOIN PaySlip P ON P.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
WHERE P.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY E.EmployeeID, E.Name
```